# clearly discernable doubt?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Yet,  the transition from alert phase  5 (imminent pandemic) to phase 6 (full-blown pandemic) was marked by **clearly discernable doubt** as to the severity of the situation.

what does "clearly discernable doubt" mean (2nd picture, 3rd line)? clearly noticeable doubt or something else?

Source: research*eu No.62 Feb 2010 (The magazine of European Research Area)

Comment: Discernable has the usual dictionary meaning,  noticeable is a synonym.

Answer (score 1):

```
"discernible" = able to be seen, recognized or understood (Cambridge)

"clearly" = added as emphasis 
"clearly discernible" = able to be clearly seen or clearly recognized

"clearly discernible doubt" = doubt that is clearly recognized
"clearly discernible doubt" = clearly recognized doubt
```

Contrast with "barely discernible" which indicates it is not easily seen or recognized.